# error 404 en aplicacion node js en heroku

Tags: javascript, nodejs, socket.io, heroku

Estoy tratando de replicar un ejemplo para recibir en tiempo real unos datos para emular agregar una asignatura, pero por mas que suba y/o cambie la forma sigue existiendo dicho error.

#### Error

```
POST https://nuevohorario.herokuapp.com/enviarAsignatura 404 (Not Found)

Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":"<h1>Not Found</h1>\n<h2></h2>\n<pre></pre>\n","status":404,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"/enviarAsignatura","data":{"data":"calculo"},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},"statusText":"Not Found"}
```

​

#### Cliente - Angular y Socket.IO

```
.controller('ctrl-asignatura',function($scope,sk,$http){

                        $scope.date= new Date();
                        $scope.data=[];
                        var vector = [];
                        $scope.m=function(){

                            //$scope.data.push($scope.informacion);
                            //console.log(vector)

                            $http.post('/enviarAsignatura', {data : $scope.asignatura}).then(function(response){
                                console.log(response);
                            })

                        }

                       sk.on('registrar',function(s){
                            alert(s);
                        });
```

#### Servidor - Node Js y Socket.IO

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var misocket = require('../routes/misocket');

/* GET users listing. */
router.post('/enviarAsignatura', function(req, res, next) {

    console.log(misocket);

    misocket.emit("registrar",req.body);
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(200).json({
        message  : "send message"
    });

});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Donde respondan primero, luego *linkeo* la respuesta

Comment: El error es 404 (Not found), pero me parece que todo esta bien, quizas falta desployear heroku

Comment: El problema en todo caso no es con angular, las peticiones se hacen correctamente, incluso lo probe con `curl` , el problema es en el server

Comment: O sea que el problema es con heroku directamente?

Comment: jeje, No es que heroku este buggy :), puedes revisar el estado de tu aplicacion en heroku?, sabes si esta usando los ultimos cambios?

Comment: Claro hago modificaciones y las acepta.

Comment: @Dolmenes deja miro a ver

Comment: @Dolmenes pero lo que no logro comprender, es que solo cambie el nombre de unas variables, y el nombre de por ejemplo la ruta, deberia afectar tanto?

Comment: Ya volví.  [¿ chat ?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol)

Answer (score 0):

Estás creando mal las conexiones. Por ejemplo para http tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

como ves, los websockets se envían bajo el servidor http. Para https será lo mismo pero añadiendo también los certificados supongo. Suerte! :)